# First two lines of NSString with width and font given

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsstring

I've got a long **NSString**, **UIFont** and desired **width**. I'd like to get only two first lines of the string that fits the width with given UIFont. By "get" I mean getting a substring. The second line may be truncated and there must be a word wrap into the first line taken into consideration.

How can I achieve this? Please show me the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a simple, clean elegant way to do this.  But if you look at the [NSString UIKit Additions reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html), there are methods that might help get a good approximation.

In particular, look at:

```
 CGSize aSize = 
 [ myString  sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)aFont 
        constrainedToSize:(CGSize ) aSize ];
```

Use aSize with your desired width and 2*fontSize (for 2 lines) for your desired height.
Take the resulting width (aSize.width) and divide by your font size.  This should approximate where your string would get truncated if it were to fit in this box.

Now unfortunately, you need to font ratio (point size to width ratio), which I don't know how to get.  I've determined empiracly that it's between 4 and 6, but that's like saying pi is about 3.

At any rate, the approximate index where your string gets truncated will be

```
 ( fontRatio * aSize.width ) / fontSize;
```

I wrote a small simulator project to test out the various combinations of line width, font ratio, font size, etc, which you're welcome to.  It's here: [string test project](http://www.cagefreesoftware.com/temp/StringSizeTest.zip)

Comment: I played a lot with it and it seems that there is no an easy solution for this. However, this answer gives the best approximation. Thanks!

Comment: @RafałSroka - NP.  I'm curious why you need to know this without actually displaying it.

Comment: I am displaying it but later, I'm filling UITableViewCells with it. I just don't want to store too much data I don't need.

Comment: Ah, premature optimization.  Why not just chop an arbitrary 500 characters off the front and use that?  Unless you have thousands of these, that's not going to be "too much data".

Comment: That's how I did it at the beginning but that would be too easy. I needed a better approximation.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
- (NSString*) stringWithString:(NSString*)longString width:(float)width font:(UIFont*)font {

    if([longString sizeWithFont:font].width < width) {
        return longString;
    }

    NSMutableString* mutString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@""];
    int i = 0;
    while ([mutString sizeWithFont:font].width < width && i < [longString length]) {
        unichar ch = [longString characterAtIndex:i];
        [mutString appendString:[NSString stringWithCharacters:&ch length:1]];
        i++;
    }

    NSString* shortenedString = [mutString substringToIndex:[mutString length] - 1];

    return shortenedString;
}
```

Basically I add the characters one by one and check everytime if the desired width is reached or not.

Edit:

With word wrapping and two lines you can adapt the code from above and use the following to check the size:

```
[mutString sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(9999999, font.lineHeight*2) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap]
```

Instead of individual characters you can also do the same with words:

```
[longString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]
```

This returns an array that contains all the words in the string which you can use to loop through.

Comment: The main idea is good but this does not take into consideration the word wrapping.

Comment: Ok, so you do want word wrapping? With a maximum of two lines? And do you care about truncation in the individual lines?

Comment: Yeap, the last line can truncate and there must be a word wrap taken into consideration. I have thousands of very long strings that I do not want to store because I only need two first lines that can fit into desired width.

Answer (score 0):

You can try having the first two lines of text in a `UILabel` of the necessary width. you can set the font for the this label.
Then you can have another label which holds the remaining portion of the text with a different font.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't want to use UILabel to do this. I just need a substring of my string.

Answer (score 0):

By "get" do you mean draw it, truncating after the first 2 lines?  Or retrieve a string that represents what fits into the space for those first 2 lines?

For the former, you can just draw it, and the UILabel will truncate for you.

For the latter, I think you're going to have to do the word breaking yourself and measure the substrings to figure out what fits.

Comment: By "get" I mean getting a substring.

Answer (score 0):

```
const int kPadding = 4; // Padding for the diference between the font's height and the line height - it's 2 for front and 2 for bottom

float maxHeight = (FONT_SIZE+kPadding)*kNumberOfLinesYouNeed;
CGSize labelSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:yourFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(kYourNeededWidth, maxHeight) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
youLabel.frame=CGRectMake(yourX, yourY, kYourNeededWidth, maxHeight);
```

I'm sorry for any mistakes. I have written this form my head.

Comment: I just need a substring of my string. I don't want labels with desired height.